# Recursive nested for-loops to implement specific Permutations at runtime

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive funtion that implements n nested for-loops, where n is decided at runtime, which give me all possible combinations of the numbers 1-x. So for x=3 that would be

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
```

I want each single permutation to be then saved into a vector.
I've found many answers on how to implement nested for-loops as recursive functions, but none yield quite the result i want. Then some answers which only work with a hard-coded amount of for-loops, that i just can't get to work dynamically (number decided at runtime). Then some answers, where one permutation only ever has one of each number, which i dont want (i also need permutations like 2-2-2 or 3-3-3).
It seems like such a simple problem, but i just can't figure it out. Any help would be insanely appreciated

Comment: what did you try? SO is not a codewriting service

Comment: btw thats not permuatations. Permuations of {1,2,3} would be {1,3,2},{2,3,1},{2,1,3},{3,1,2} and {3,2,1}

Comment: @user463035818, they are permutations... just not the permutations you would get by applying `std::next_permutation`.  These are [permutations with repetition](https://www.ck12.org/book/CK-12-Basic-Probability-and-Statistics-Concepts-A-Full-Course/section/2.4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void getPerm(int from, int to, std::vector<int>& curr, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& result) {
    bool alreadySetToOne  = false;
    int  nextFrom = 0;
    if (curr.size() == to) {
        result.push_back(curr);
        return;
    }

    if (from > 1 && !alreadySetToOne) {
        from = 1;
        alreadySetToOne = true;
    }

    for (int i=from; i <= to; ++i) {
        curr.push_back(i);
        getPerm(i, to, curr, result);
        curr.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto n = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> results;
    std::vector<int> curr;
    std::cout << "Put number ...\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    getPerm(1, n, curr, results);


    //Check results
    for (int i=0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < results[i].size(); ++j) {
            std::cout << results[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Just use first and last number to generate you sequence and in each recursion iterate only up to n numbers from first one.

Answer (score -1):

```
void Foo(vector<vector<int>>& list, const int& n)
{
    if(list.empty())
    {
        list.push_back(vector<int>(n,1));
        return Foo(list,n);
    }

    vector<int> entry(list.back());
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(entry.at(i) < n)
        {
            entry[i]++;
            list.push_back(entry);

            return Foo(list,n);
        }

        entry[i] = 1;
    }
}

// test case
vector<vector<int>> list;
Foo(list,3);
```

If empty, this will initialize a size n vector of ints to 1. Then each iteration it will clone the last entry and loop down the indices from least to most significant, incrementing if less than n and recursing or else resetting to 1 and continuing to the next most siginificant index until it's complete.